# Nextauth logins into wrong provider's account

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

So I have this strange bug where when I click on my 'Login to Facebook' button on the sign in page, it instead logs me into my gmail account.

I have two providers, Gmail and Facebook, and until recently they were both working as intended.  I recently attempted to implement a feature where a user was added to a group based on url params instead of a code emailed to them, and have since reverted to the original (basically commented out all the code pertaining to it), so that it would just join users by an inputted code.  While attempting to implement this feature I was switching back and forth between the two accounts quite often, inviting from the gmail account, logging out and then joining via the invite email with the FB linked account.

For some reason, now when I click the facebook provider login button, it logs me into my primary gmail account.  When I try to log in with other gmail accounts, it works as intended.

Is there some way to refresh the data it has saved?

Here is my auth.ts:

```
import {
  getServerSession,
  type NextAuthOptions,
  type DefaultSession,
} from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import FacebookProvider from "next-auth/providers/facebook";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { env } from "~/env.mjs";
import { prisma } from "~/server/db";
import type { UserRole } from "@prisma/client";

/**
 * Module augmentation for `next-auth` types. Allows us to add custom properties to the `session`
 * object and keep type safety.
 *
 * @see https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation
 */
declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session extends DefaultSession {
    user: {
      id: string;
      email?: string | null | undefined;
      image?: string | null | undefined;
      name?: string | null | undefined;
      // ...other properties
      role: UserRole;
    } & DefaultSession["user"];
  }

  interface User {
    // ...other properties
    role: UserRole;
    email?: string | null | undefined;
    image?: string | null | undefined;
    name?: string | null | undefined;
  }
}

/**
 * Options for NextAuth.js used to configure adapters, providers, callbacks, etc.
 *
 * @see https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options
 */
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    session({ session, user }) {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = user.id;

        session.user.role = user.role;
        session.user.email = user.email;
        session.user.image = user.image;
        session.user.name = user.name;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    FacebookProvider({
      clientId: env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    /**
     * ...add more providers here.
     *
     * Most other providers require a bit more work than the Discord provider. For example, the
     * GitHub provider requires you to add the `refresh_token_expires_in` field to the Account
     * model. Refer to the NextAuth.js docs for the provider you want to use. Example:
     *
     * @see https://next-auth.js.org/providers/github
     */
  ],
  pages: {
    newUser: "/firstLogin",
  },
};

/**
 * Wrapper for `getServerSession` so that you don't need to import the `authOptions` in every file.
 *
 * @see https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs
 */
export const getServerAuthSession = (ctx: {
  req: GetServerSidePropsContext["req"];
  res: GetServerSidePropsContext["res"];
}) => {
  return getServerSession(ctx.req, ctx.res, authOptions);
};
```